# Fill up missing values in an R dataframe using the df itself

Tags: r, dataframe, machine-learning, missing-data

Below is my sample dataset -

[image]

I have to fill in item weight according to the weight of other rows where the item_id and Item_type is the same. For example, Item_wt of third observation must be "5.6". 
Can you please suggest a way to fill in the missing values in R? I tried many techniques but couldn't get what i wanted. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `NULL` is `NA`, after grouping by 'item_ID', 'item_Type', get the first non NA 'item_wt'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(item_ID, item_Type) %>%
    mutate(item_wt = item_wt[!is.na(item_wt)][1])
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   item_ID, item_Type [3]
#  item_ID item_wt item_Type
#    <chr>   <dbl>     <chr>
#1    T001     5.6     Dairy
#2    T002     9.2    Snacks
#3    T001     5.6     Dairy
#4    T004     3.9    Drinks
#5    T002     9.2    Snacks
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, item_wt := item_wt[!is.na(item_wt)][1], .(item_ID, item_Type)]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(item_ID = c('T001', 'T002', 'T001', 'T004', 'T002'),
     item_wt = c(5.6, 9.2, NA, 3.9, NA),
     item_Type = c("Dairy", "Snacks", "Dairy", "Drinks", "Snacks"),
     stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing multiple options. I will try this as well.

Answer (score 2):

Base R solution using [ave](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/ave.html) function :

```
DF <- data.frame(Item_ID=c('T001','T002','T001','T004','T002'),
                 Item_wt=c(5.6,9.2,NA,3.9,NA),
                 Item_Type=c('Dairy','Snacks','Dairy','Drinks','Snacks'))

g <- ave(1:nrow(DF),DF$Item_ID,DF$Item_Type,FUN=function(i)mean(DF$Item_wt[i],na.rm=TRUE))
DF$Item_wt[is.na(DF$Item_wt)] <- g[is.na(DF$Item_wt)]

> DF
  Item_ID Item_wt Item_Type
1    T001     5.6     Dairy
2    T002     9.2    Snacks
3    T001     5.6     Dairy
4    T004     3.9    Drinks
5    T002     9.2    Snacks
```

Comment: Thank you so much. it worked. wanted to look for a native R func. really helped.

Answer (score 0):

Use `group_by` from dplyr and `fill` from tidyr.

```
library(tidyverse)

 Filled_Item_Wts <- df1 %>%
 group_by(Item_ID, Item_Type) %>%
 fill(Item_wt)



Item_ID Item_wt Item_Type
    <chr>   <dbl>     <chr>
1    T001     5.6     Dairy
2    T001     5.6     Dairy
3    T002     9.2    Snacks
4    T002     9.2    Snacks
5    T004     3.9    Drinks
```

Answer (score 0):

For imputation of Missing Data in R tools, the best available packages are Missforest, mice ,Roughset. Roughset package is good for medical dataset. For Categorical data-set, we can use missforest package for best result.

Comment: Please add some useful links and/or code in order for the answer to be complete